# How to add the image in the PDF from URL in android java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, itext

I am using this library

implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.1.15'
implementation 'com.itextpdf:layout:7.1.15'

I want to add the image in the header of the pdf document

String Url = "https://image.jpg"

table1.addCell(new Cell(3, 1).add(image1));
table1.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("")));
table1.addCell(new Cell(1, 2).add(new Paragraph("Company Name")).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).setFontSize(fontSize).setBold());